# Can I have a multi-level path for my Actuator base-path?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm trying to configure my Springboot Actuator dependency a bit for some custom needs. Specifically the path in which I access the actuator endpoints.

I'll preface this with it works locally out of the box...but because of some org requirements, I need to change the path to fit a specific url path. I've found some docs like in the image below and have been able to successfully change the path to my actuator to something like `localhost:8080/test/health`. So that's all fine and dandy.

My problem is I need to change the path to actuator to something like `localhost:8080/part1/part2/health` (`part1` and `part2` would be obviously specific to my orgs needs, but the idea remains.

It's also worth mentioning this project isn't *100%* springboot...it's a combo of Jax-RS (Also called Jersey I believe) and Springboot....I think this is the root of the problem, but I'm not sure.

Any help would be super appreciated.
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `management.endpoints.web.base-path=/part1/part2` ?

Comment: I have to no avail. I did just update original post with this like "It's also worth mentioning this project isn't 100% springboot...it's a combo of Jax-RS (Also called Jersey I believe) and Springboot....I think this is the root of the problem, but I'm not sure."

Comment: So you have tried `management.endpoints.web.base-path=/part1/part2`? And it is not working? If so, any error message?

Comment: Yes I have - I get a 404 error.